# Debug in WebStorm where the address is not localhost

Tags: node.js, webstorm, hosts

I am trying to debug a project which needed a mapping in the hosts files from localhost to some other address like this

```
127.0.0.1  devproject.com
```

I can access the web app fine with a port number like this: `devproject.com:3000` however this settings doesn't work when I try to debug in WebStorm?

Is there a way to tell WebStorm about this hosts file settings? Or I need to use a whole new settings? I am using node.js debug profile.

Comment: *(for reference purposes)* Same asked on WebStorm Forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000106490-Debug-in-WebStorm-where-the-address-is-not-localhost

Answer (score 1):

When debugging, you need using same URL as you normally use to access your application; so, to start debugging, you just need to specify `http://devproject.com:3000` as `URL` in [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) Run configuration. See https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Starting+a+JavaScript+debug+session#StartingaJavaScriptdebugsession-Startingadebugsessionwhenusingadifferentwebserver

Comment: I am getting "GET http://devproject.com:3000 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" in the debug console when I start debugging

Comment: strange... Is the server running? If you can access your application using `http://devproject.com:3000` outside WebStorm, it should work equally well in WebStorm, as all it does is starting the browser and passing specified URL to it

Comment: does not work for me as well: could not resolve host - only ip should be specified. some jet brains bug.

Comment: doesn't look like WebStorm issue. Once again - webstorm itself doesn't connect to your host, it's the browser that is establishing a connection. make sure that there is no proxy, etc. setting blocking access to host name